# What is it called when locals intentionally mispronounce their home town?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

What is it called when locals intentionally "mispronounce" (compared to the common or historical pronunciation) their home town or other words? I've read somewhere a while back that it was intended to know the difference between a local and a non-local person, e.g. someone who might not belong there.

Comment: One could make an argument that it's the _correct_ pronunciation.

Comment: It's called "Louisville".

Comment: @Spencer, Sometimes, yes, othertimes, no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you by any chance conflating the concepts of an ***endonym*** and a ***shibboleth***?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exonym_and_endonym

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shibboleth

*Shibboleths* are when the pronunciation of word distinguishes a 'non-local' from a 'local', and *endonyms* are an indigenous name or pronunciation, as opposed to the *exonym* used by outsiders. Neither word applies exclusively to placenames, but placenames are commonly examples of both.